# What is the most efficient way of saving the pages visited by an anonymous user (analytics)?

Tags: meteor

**I am creating an interactive survey application.**

Right now, I have a questions collection, and an options collection.

I want a visitor to be able to click through the questions.

**Their responses should be saved on the server, even if they don't create an account.**

What is the most efficient way of going about this?

I'm thinking along the lines of a Responses collection that is created when a user first visits (?tied to a user with the meteor-accounts-anonymous package?).
[Alternative: Session variable with an array of the responses?]

If I go with this:

How can I associate an entry in the responses collection with the current session?

I've been trying with using meteor-accounts-anonymous and then on Meteor.startup doing Meteor.loginAnonymously();, and then inserting a Response.

However I can't seem to get the inserted Response associated with the userId.

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  Meteor.loginAnonymously();

  Responses.insert({
    userId: Meteor.userId(),
    list: []
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The atmosphere project (the one at atmosphere.meteor.com) stores this on the server in `Meteor.publish`.

Every time a user requests a collection this would be logged.

You could see the corresponding file at : https://github.com/oortcloud/atmosphere/blob/master/app/server/publish.js